# Window object in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, window

If i define a window object like this :

```
w_score = Window().partitionBy("HUB_ID").orderBy(F.col("coefficient").desc(), F.col("LastUpdateDate").desc())
```

And another one, like this :

```
w_score_prim = w_score.orderBy(F.col("Primary"))
```

The new object, `w_score_prim` is equivalent to which one ? :

```
Window().partitionBy("HUB_ID").orderBy(F.col("coefficient").desc(), F.col("LastUpdateDate").desc(), F.col("Primary"))
or 
Window().partitionBy("HUB_ID").orderBy(F.col("Primary"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiple `orderBy()` call, last `orderBy` overwrites all previously called `orderBy`. So to answer your question - it would be

```
Window().partitionBy("HUB_ID").orderBy(F.col("Primary"))
```

It can be better illustrated using below 3 use cases:

- case 1: If you want to order by column `a` (ascending) and then `b` (ascending) try this example.
- case 2: If you call `orderBy()` twice (or multiple times) then it considers the last call as the final ordering call. So in this example it orders by column `b` 'only'.
- case 3: Same (as case 2) happens here. It orders by column `b` and has ignored column `a` ordering.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1, 3, 1, 10],
    [1, 0, 2, 20],
    [3, 2, 3, 30],
    [2, 1, 6, 40],
    [2, 1, 4, 50],
    [2, 2, 5, 60]
]).toDF(('id', 'a', 'b', 'val'))

#case 1
w = Window.partitionBy().partitionBy("id").orderBy(f.col("a"), f.col("b"))
df1 = df.withColumn("c", f.sum(f.col("val")).over(w))
df1.show()

#case 2
w_2 = Window.partitionBy().partitionBy("id").orderBy(f.col("a")).orderBy(f.col("b"))
df2 = df.withColumn("c", f.sum(f.col("val")).over(w_2))
df2.show()

#case 3
w_3 = Window.partitionBy().partitionBy("id").orderBy(f.col("a"))
w_3 = w_3.orderBy("b")
df3 = df.withColumn("c", f.sum(f.col("val")).over(w_3))
df3.show()
```

Output is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|val|  c|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  2| 20| 20|
|  1|  3|  1| 10| 30|
|  3|  2|  3| 30| 30|
|  2|  1|  4| 50| 50|
|  2|  1|  6| 40| 90|
|  2|  2|  5| 60|150|
+---+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|val|  c|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  1| 10| 10|
|  1|  0|  2| 20| 30|
|  3|  2|  3| 30| 30|
|  2|  1|  4| 50| 50|
|  2|  2|  5| 60|110|
|  2|  1|  6| 40|150|
+---+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|val|  c|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  1| 10| 10|
|  1|  0|  2| 20| 30|
|  3|  2|  3| 30| 30|
|  2|  1|  4| 50| 50|
|  2|  2|  5| 60|110|
|  2|  1|  6| 40|150|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```